# Messaging system for MySQL - improve insert speeds while maintaing select speeds

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I want to create a messaging system with mySQL. I have the following columns in an innodb table:

- MSG_ID (int)
- USERID_SENDER (int)
- USERID_RECIEVER (int)
- TIMESTAMP_SENT (varchar(2000))

There are 3 queries that will be used on this table:

```
Select    * 
From      msgTable 
Where     USERID_RECIEVER = [id of the user who the message was sent to].
```

The other will be to insert a row (a new message) and the last will be a DELETE once the row has been read. To stress test I used a billion rows (since user's can send multiple messages).

I have inserted a billion test rows which have a b-tree index on `USERID_RECIEVER` and a Unique index on the primary key `MSG_ID`. The reads are quite fast (~1 second) but the inserts are much too slow (10+ minutes). This is running on a 6-core Intel i7 with 16gb ram. If I remove the indexes the inserts are a little faster since there is just one index to rebuild now, but then the reads are terribly slow. With the nature of a messaging system both select and insert I believe will be called the same amount of times roughly.

Is there anything else I can do to increase the performance so that the inserts also happen in about ~1-2 seconds? I tried to use batch inserts which helped speeds, but due to the business logic of the application it is not practical.

Comment: Do you ever have any periods of no (or very low) activity? If so, you might consider just flagging a row once it has been read, then do the actual deletion during off hours. If you do it this way, you may want to drop the index, do the bulk delete, then re-add the index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and good suggestion, unfortunatly I don't think there will be low activity.

Comment: Is a billion rows realistic?

Comment: yes, the messages include both user and system generated messages, so we expect to have close to a billion in a few month